Frobenius method for solving differential equation
Need help solving this differential equation$$xy''+(x+l)y'+ly=0$$ where $l\in \mathbb{R}$\
I tried using the Frobenius method.
$x_0=0$ is a regular singular point and
Assume that we have the solution of the following form:$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+r}$
$y' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (n+r) x^{n+r-1}$
$ y'' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (n+r)(n+r-1) x^{n+r-2}$
then,Substituting and simplifying we get:
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (n+r)(n+r-1) x^{n+r-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (n+r) x^{n+r} + l \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (n+r) x^{n+r-1} + l \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+r} = 0
   $$
Combining and reordering gives us:
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n [(n+r)(n+r-1) + l(n+r)] x^{n+r-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n [(n+r) + l] x^{n+r} = 0
   $$
Now,$r(r-1)+lr=0$ or $r=0$ and $r=-l+1$
introducing new variable k=n-1 and again changing back gives us
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n [(n+r)(n+r-1) + l(n+r)] x^{n+r-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} [n-1+r + l] x^{n+r-1} = 0
   $$
simplifying gives us:
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n [(n+r)] x^{n+r-1} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^{n+r=1} = 0
   $$ $r=0$ gives us the following recurrence relation: for $n=1,2, \cdots $
$a_n=\frac{-a_{n-1}}{n}$ which gives us one of the solution as :
$y_1(x)=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n a_0 x^n}{n!}$

"Is this one of the solution of the above given differential equation?"  Check it by substituting into the DE.

Unless you are required to go Frobenius path, it is an overkill here. Notice that $$xy''+(x+l)y'+ly = x(y'' + y') + l(y' + y) = x(y'+y)' + l(y'+y)$$, and have a first order ODE for $z=y'+y$: $$xz' + lz = 0$$. The rest is very straightforward.

The comment is correct - the best way to know whether this is a solution or not is to simply check.
However, a nice way to check is to note that your solution is simply
$ y(x)=a_0 e^{-x}$
(by the well known Taylor series for $e^x$).
Then we have
$y'(x)=-a_0 e^{-x}$, $y''(x)=a_0 e^{-x} $.
We can now check that
$xy''+(x+l)y'+ly =a_0 xe^{-x} - (x+l)a_0 e^{-x} + la_0 e^{-x} =0$.
So yes, your solution is indeed a solution to the differential equation.

Thank you !!! I totally missed that fact that it is e^-x. I have edited my question which is perhaps now an answer?
